# Rollover Counter Increments and Decrements

Tags: java, count, max, min

I'm attempting to make a rollover counter that increases until the max and the decreases once it get to the max. The full instructions are in the code. I'm confused on where I'm going wrong. I'm getting a couple compiling errors that don't make sense, because it's code that I think I need to use. Any thoughts?

```
/*
* Write the code for the RolloverCounter class below
* 
* In this RolloverCounter.java file you will implement a RolloverCounter class that should include:
1) A private variable to store the current count.
2) Another private variable to store the maximum value this counter can count up to.
3) A constructor with a single integer parameter used to set the maximum counter value.  The count should be set to 0.
4) An increment() method that increases the count value by 1, but sets it back to 0 if the count goes above the maximum. no parameters, returns nothing
5) A decrement() method that decreases the count value by 1, but sets it to the maximum value if it goes below 0. no parameters, returns nothing
6) A getCount() method that returns an integer of the current count value.  no parameters.
7) A reset() method that sets the count value back to 0.  no parameters, returns nothing.

Notes:
+ This class is meant to be like the values on a car's odometer readout that tick upwards through
the digits 0 to 9 and then roll back to 0. In this case, the maximum can be any positive number.
+ The count should always be a number between 0 and the maximum value that was set when the counter was created.
*/

public class RolloverCounter {
  //TODO: Write the code for the class here.

  //private variables
 private int count = 0;
 private int max = 0;

  //constructor
 public RolloverCounter(int maxCount) {
   max = maxCount; 
 }  
  //methods
  RolloverCounter c1 = new RolloverCounter(max);
  for (int i=1; i<=max; i++) {
      c1.increment();
  }
  for (int j=1; j<=max; j++) {
      c1.decrement();
  }
  RolloverCount.getCount();
  c1.reset();
  }
}
```

3 errors found:

```
File: C:\Users\kevin\CS\RolloverCounter.java  [line: 31]
Error: Syntax error on token ";", { expected after this token

File: C:\Users\kevin\CS\RolloverCounter.java  [line: 33]
Error: The method increment() is undefined for the type RolloverCounter

File: C:\Users\kevin\CS\RolloverCounter.java  [line: 36]
Error: The method decrement() is undefined for the type RolloverCounter
```

Comment: You've got executable statements that are not inside a method body.

Comment: "The method increment() is undefined for the type RolloverCounter". The message is pretty clear - your RollloverCounter does not have an `increment()` function yet. So your first step is to add it.

Answer (score 1):

That piece of code can't be understood by the compiler because it is not inside a method.

```
  //methods
  RolloverCounter c1 = new RolloverCounter(max);
  for (int i=1; i<=max; i++) {
      c1.increment();
  }
  for (int j=1; j<=max; j++) {
      c1.decrement();
  }
  RolloverCount.getCount();
  c1.reset();
  }
```

I'm not going to do your homework for you, but to get you started, here is the skeleton of the class you need to implement.

I kept what you already wrote and was correct.

```
public class RolloverCounter {
    //private variables
    private int count = 0;
    private int max = 0;

    //constructor
    public RolloverCounter(int maxCount) {
        max = maxCount;
    }

    // increases the count value by 1, but sets it back to 0 if the count goes above the maximum. 
    // returns nothing
    public void increment() {
        /* Your code here */
    }

    // decreases the count value by 1, but sets it to the maximum value if it goes below 0. 
    // returns nothing
    public void decrement() {
        /* Your code here */
    }

    // returns an integer of the current count value.
    public int getCount() {
        /* Your code here */
    }

    // sets the count value back to 0.
    // returns nothing.
    public void reset() {
        /* Your code here */
    }
}
```